# ajax, метод POST

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Не понимаю, почему, если в отправке не указать путь к файлу, то будет ошибка 404?

Например, вот так всё работает

```
 xmlhttp.open("POST","./friend.php",true);
```

Но если убрать `friend.php` и оставить только `./ то будет ошибка 404, почему так?

С методом GET, почему-то нормально всё отправляется.
Надо же всего лишь отправить данные, то есть если написать `./` то должны отправится туда, где и отправляется.

Comment: ошибки в консоли Вам ни о чем не говорят?

Comment: POST http://localhost/ajaxdr2/ 404 (Not Found)  Такая папка есть

Comment: пост метод предоставляет данные, для обработки указанному ресурсу, который не может быть директорией. Ошибка 404 должна Вам намекать на это

Comment: Я кажись понял, если указывать только корень сайта, после отправки, будет искаться индексный файл, но у меня его нету, из-за этого ошибка?

Comment: никакой индексный файл не будет "искаться". Вам нужно ссылатся на файл, нежели на директорию , как в данном случае

Comment: но он же стоит по умолчанию на любых сайтах

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65593/discussion-between-ddeadlink-and-divman).

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь закидают помидорами, но файл должен называться `index.php`. или можно изменить в `.htaccess` имя индексного файла.

Comment: Помидорами, наверно, не закидают, но в ответе явно напрашивается побольше подробностей

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/197021)

Comment: @kizoso а ты хоть вопрос прочитал?